# Configure Artifactory with grails project

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, artifactory

I am trying to configure a `Grails` project with remote `Artifactory` but failing to configure it properly.

Envionmanet setup

> 1. grails-2.4.3
> 2. artifactory.version 3.3.0

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy

grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://SERVER/artifactory/grails-remote"
    }
    credentials {
        realm = "Artifactory Realm"
        host = "SERVER"
        username = "USERNAME"
        password = "PASSWORD"
    }
}

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        mavenRepo id: 'Artifactory', url: "http://SERVER/artifactory/grails-remote"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"

        compile ":rabbitmq:1.0.0"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    }
}
```

Getting the below exception after executing the refresh-dependencies command for the project

```
Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.7, org.grails.plugins:webxml:zip:1.4.1, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.6, org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq:zip:1.0.0, org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.5.5, org.grails.plugins:database-migration:zip:1.4.0, org.grails.plugins:jquery:zip:1.11.1: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2 in Artifactory (http://SERVER/artifactory/grails-remote) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.7, org.grails.plugins:webxml:zip:1.4.1, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.6, org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq:zip:1.0.0, org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.5.5, org.grails.plugins:database-migration:zip:1.4.0, org.grails.plugins:jquery:zip:1.11.1: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2 in Artifactory (http://SERVER/artifactory/grails-remote) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.7, org.grails.plugins:webxml:zip:1.4.1, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.6, org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq:zip:1.0.0: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2 in Artifactory (http://SERVER/artifactory/grails-remote) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.7, org.grails.plugins:webxml:zip:1.4.1, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.6, org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq:zip:1.0.0: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2 in Artifactory (http://SERVER/artifactory/grails-remote)
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
Process was killed
```

I have read and tried couple of solutions as described in below link but it couldn't help

1. [How to configure grails 2.4.0 to resolve artifacts from artifactory with authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000409/how-to-configure-grails-2-4-0-to-resolve-artifacts-from-artifactory-with-authent)
2. http://wordpress.transentia.com.au/wordpress/2014/04/09/artifactory-and-grails/

**Update1:**

After looking closely into `Artifactory's apache catalina log` I found that for some of plugins it is causing some forbidden error.

```
2014-10-15 15:16:19,596 [ajp-bio-8019-exec-10] [INFO ] (o.a.r.s.RepositoryBrowsingServiceImpl:236) - Error while listing remote resources for codehaus/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-mongo: Unable to retrieve http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-mongo/: 403: Forbidden
```

Can anyone please help me to find out whats wrong with configuration?

Greetings,
Mayank

Comment: Anybody can guide me on this? Still I am on the same line.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than defining the repository authentication with `grails.project.ivy.authentication`, You should probably define the repository with:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        ....
        mavenRepo(name: 'name', url: 'https://host/artifactory/reponame') {
            auth(username: 'username', password: 'password')
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried with the changes you suggested but couldn't help. Am still running with same error. You have mentioned grailsCentral() in repositories tag, I believe it will directly  download the plugin from grails central repo, but I want all the library and plugin download should go through the Artifactory.

Comment: Are you sure your artifactory properly proxies grails central?

Comment: Can you just tell me how do I validate?

Comment: You need to add Grails central as a remote repository in Artifactory